# Matlab Black Scholes formula how to get volatility from B&S price

Tags: matlab, finance, solver, volatility

I'm quite beginning with matlab and have a question maybe simple ?

i got Black&Scholes formula to get a call option price with the following input parameters :
S = stock price, K = strike , r = rate, T = time to expiration , sigma = volatility

Call option price is given by :

```
C(S,K,r,t,sigma) = S *N(d1) - K e^-rT *N(d2)
d1 = (1/sqrt(T))*(ln(S/K)+(r+0.5*sigma^2)*T)
d2 = d1 - sigma*sqrt(T)
```

I have no probleme with this function but i need to get the black scholes volatility.

I have as inputs : `S, K , r , T , BlackScholesPrice` and i want to return sigma.

I tried with "syms sig; solve ("blackscholesequation"==blacksholesprice, sig);" but there's nothing to do, i always get an error

```
"Error using symfun>validateArgNames (line 211)
Second input must be a scalar or vector of unique symbolic variables.

Error in symfun (line 45)
            y.vars = validateArgNames(inputs);

Error in sym/subsasgn (line 762)
                C = symfun(B,[inds{:}]);

Error in normcdf>localnormcdf (line 100)
    p(sigma==0 & x<mu) = 0;

Error in normcdf (line 46)
[varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] = localnormcdf(uflag,x,varargin{:});

Error in BlackScholesInverse (line 3)
solve(S0*normcdf((log(S0/K)+(r+0.5*sig*sig)*T)*(1/(sig*sqrt(T))))-K*exp(-r*T)*normcdf((log(S0/K)+(r+0.5*sig*sig)*T)*(1/(sig*sqrt(T)))-sig*sqrt(T))==
prixBS,sig)"
```

If anybody got an idea it would be awesome. Thx all'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find implied volatility. For that you can use [blsimpv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/blsimpv.html). It would be easier to use this function, just that you need to give the inputs according.

Comment: Are you sure that the volatility in B&S formula and the implied vol are the same ?